# SQL - Get last day of every month of the current year - SQLITE3

Tags: sql, date, sqlite

I have scurried through the SO and found a lot of helpful queries to do this, but not exactly what I want, or even they say it is the answer but it doesn't work at all for sqlite3.

So here we go. I want to return all data on the last day of every month of the current year. Like below: (just ignore the time, just wanted to add it in for how my field actually looks like)

```
Name | Date_Added
=================================
Bob  | 2018-01-31 05:23:06.021421
Bob  | 2018-02-28 14:16:03.076021
Bob  | 2018-03-31 13:16:03.076021
Bob  | 2018-04-30 13:16:03.076021
Bob  | 2018-05-31 13:16:03.076021
Bob  | 2018-06-04 13:16:03.076021
Mary | 2018-01-31 13:16:03.076021
Mary | 2018-02-28 13:16:03.076021
Mary | 2018-03-31 13:16:03.076021
Mary | 2018-04-30 13:16:03.076021
Mary | 2018-05-31 13:16:03.076021
Mary | 2018-06-04 13:16:03.076021
```

I have tried things like:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE date('now','start of month','-1 month','-1 day') ORDER BY "Name"
```

But it seems that it still send data that isn't just on the last day

Any help or direction will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the date is the last day of the month, then the month will be different if you add one day:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName 
    WHERE 
        strftime("%m", Date_Added) != strftime("%m", Date_Added, "+1 day")
            AND 
        strftime("%Y", Date_Added) = strftime("%Y", "now")
ORDER BY "Name";
```

Comment: Excellent Answer! My answer is just the long way around. But I ran into a slight problem, I need to get the last data of the month, so if January's last data was on the 23rd then it must show the 23rd rather trying to query the 31st? I'll mark yours as the right answer for the current question.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely a different question. When you post it, be sure to specify exactly what data you're looking for (Just the last row of each month? All data from the last day of each month that had data? Last row of each month for each `Name`?)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE
 "Date_added" BETWEEN date('2018-12-30','start of month','-10 month','-1 day') AND date('2018-12-30','start of month','-10 month','0 day') OR 
 "Date_added" BETWEEN date('2018-12-30','start of month','-9 month','-1 day') AND date('2018-12-30','start of month','-9 month','0 day') OR 
 "Date_added" BETWEEN date('2018-12-30','start of month','-8 month','-1 day') AND date('2018-12-30','start of month','-8 month','0 day') OR 
 "Date_added" BETWEEN date('2018-12-30','start of month','-7 month','-1 day') AND date('2018-12-30','start of month','-7 month','0 day') OR 
 "Date_added" BETWEEN date('2018-12-30','start of month','-6 month','-1 day') AND date('2018-12-30','start of month','-6 month','0 day') OR 
 "Date_added" BETWEEN date('2018-12-30','start of month','-5 month','-1 day') AND date('2018-12-30','start of month','-5 month','0 day') OR 
 "Date_added" BETWEEN date('2018-12-30','start of month','-4 month','-1 day') AND date('2018-12-30','start of month','-4 month','0 day') OR 
 "Date_added" BETWEEN date('2018-12-30','start of month','-3 month','-1 day') AND date('2018-12-30','start of month','-3 month','0 day') OR 
 "Date_added" BETWEEN date('2018-12-30','start of month','-2 month','-1 day') AND date('2018-12-30','start of month','-2 month','0 day') OR 
 "Date_added" BETWEEN date('2018-12-30','start of month','-1 month','-1 day') AND date('2018-12-30','start of month','-1 month','0 day') OR 
 "Date_added" BETWEEN date('2018-12-30','start of month','0 month','-1 day') AND date('2018-12-30','start of month','0 month','0 day') 
ORDER BY "Name"
```

Quite tedious, but is working for me!